# Can muggles see the Dark Mark skull cloud?

Tags: harry-potter, the-half-blood-prince, the-goblet-of-fire

**Can muggles see the skull with serpent cloud Dark Mark produced by Death Eaters?**

Goblet of Fire example -

> Then he realised it was a colossal skull, comprised of what looked
>   like emerald stars, with a serpent protruding from its mouth like a
>   tongue. As they watched, it rose higher and higher, blazing in a haze
>   of greenish smoke, etched against the black sky like a new
>   constellation.

Also seen at the start of the Half-Blood Prince.

It seems this is certainly no ordinary cloud formation so should be visible and provoke reaction?

I know the Death Eaters don't care about breaking the Wizarding Law or alerting/scaring muggles, but I was wondering if they could see this formation?

Comment: Is this question about the books, since you quote an actual book paraghraph there?

Comment: If this is a question about the books, then it's best to ask it on [scifi.se].

Comment: However, if you're only concerned about the movies, then either this site or that one is fine (but it's generally frowned upon to cross-post).

Comment: Just using the books as supporting evidence. Mainly was thinking about the scene at the start of the Half-Blood Prince when the office watches the weather change outside and then the skull appears. But noted

Answer (score 1):

**Probably**

From [Pottetmore](https://www.pottermore.com/quote/voldemorts-sign), the purpose of *Morsmordre* is:

> [To cast] a giant skull with a serpent's tongue into the clouds for all to see

Considering Voldemort's ultimate goal was to 'put muggles in their place', it makes sense that the Dark Mark would be visible to everyone.

Making it non visible to muggles wouldn't be as effective if you're trying to scare a large group at once.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stated book or movies that would make it hidden to muggles. It is a pretty basic elemental magic, nothing that seems particularly difficult aside from the scale. Remember, pretty much all magic can be seen and affects muggles just as much as they affect wizard kind. Which is a problem that is addressed by magical law prohibiting magic in front if muggles. The Ministry must clean these messes up. Muggles that witness magic are made to forget and the wizards at fault punished. If magic could easily be hidden from muggle eyes, then there would not be a need for the law.

Everything we see says that most magic can't be hidden. This would not be an exception unless we are told otherwise. Also note the muggle prime minister and government are aware of wizard kind and magic, and reports of magic come through those channels to the Ministry.